# JS if there is a slider show it

Tags: javascript

I'm no JS expert but I'm trying to alter this so that if there is a royalslider display it… if there isn't display the static image and the title and description. Any ideas as to why this isn't working? my head is currently spinning… I've left some space around the section I'm trying to add to the code under //royal slider fix and currently its just showing the title and description from the if statement. But, the markup is showing the slider div and outputting the code.

Any help would be very appreciated! You can preview this code and what I'm trying to do here... http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/?page_id=2

```
;(function($) {

$.fn.SuperBox = function(options) {

    var superbox      = $('<div class="superbox-show"></div>');
    var superboximg   = $('<img src="" class="superbox-current-img">');
    var superboxclose = $('<div class="superbox-close"></div>');

    superbox.append(superboximg).append(superboxclose);

    return this.each(function() {

        $('.superbox').on('click', '.superbox-list', function() {

            //allows for superbox to work inside of quicksand
            $('ul.filterable-grid').css({overflow: 'visible'});

            var currentimg = $(this).find('.superbox-img');
            superbox.find('.title').remove(); 
            superbox.find('.description').remove(); 

            var imgData = currentimg.data();
            superboximg.attr('src', imgData.img);
            if (imgData.title) { superbox.append('<h3 class="title">'+imgData.title+'</h3>'); }
            if (imgData.description) { superbox.append('<div class="description">' + imgData.description + '</div>'); }









//royal slider fix              
superbox.find('.royalSlider').remove(); // remove the slider from previous events
var imgData = currentimg.data();
var sliderData = currentimg.next('.royalSlider'); // grab the slider html that we want to insert

superboximg.attr('src', imgData.img); 

if (sliderData) { // show the slider if there is one
    superbox.clone().append(sliderData); // clone the element so we don't loose it for the next time the user clicks
} else { // if there is no slider proceed as before
    if (imgData.img) {
        superbox.append(imgData.img);
    }
    if (imgData.title) {
        superbox.append('<h3 class="title">' + imgData.title + '</h3>');
    }
    if (imgData.description) {
        superbox.append('<div class="description">' + imgData.description + '</div>');
    }
}












            if($('.superbox-current-img').css('opacity') == 0) {
                $('.superbox-current-img').animate({opacity: 1});
            }

            if ($(this).next().hasClass('superbox-show')) {
                superbox.toggle();
            } else {
                superbox.insertAfter(this).css('display', 'block');
            }

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop:superbox.position().top - currentimg.width()
            }, 'medium');

        });


        $('.superbox').on('hover', '.superbox-list', function(e) {
            $(this).find('.overlay').stop()[(e.type == 'mouseenter') ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']('slow');
        });


        $('.superbox').on('click', '.superbox-close', function() {
            $('.superbox-current-img').animate({opacity: 100}, 200, function() {
                $('.superbox-show').slideUp();
            });
        });

    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Format the code first and jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Is it formatted wrong? I tried to indent to make it readable.

Comment: Started a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/EwbXh/9/

Comment: I can't seem to get it working on jsfiddle for some reason. WIll keep trying

Answer (score 0):

This is only intended to be hints, not an attempt to solve the entire problem.

Try this:

```
var superbox      = $('<div class="superbox-show"/>');
var superboximg   = $('<img src="" class="superbox-current-img"/>');
var superboxclose = $('<div class="superbox-close"/>');
```

---

```
if (sliderData.length > 0)
```

Where is imgData.img getting its value?

Comment: I made it an answer instead of a comment just to get the syntax highlightning

Comment: Thank you for the hints. This has been a HUGE PAIN! I really appreciate it!

Comment: no, I'm pretty confused and feel like I'm in over my head. :-/

Comment: Understandably, exercise however is how you improve :)